# Java Contains illegal character for hexBinary

Tags: java, aes

the problem I'm facing is that when I read from file(string) for example:

- ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff

It shows that Error **"contains illegal character for hexBinary: ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"** but when I give the statement as a basic ***String = ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;*** everything works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
System.out.println( "128-bit hex key example: ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff" );

try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\TESTS\\tests.txt"))) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();


Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
 System.out.println( "Enter 128-bit hex key: " );
 final String keyHex = scanner.nextLine();

 final String plaintextHex = "aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccff";

SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(DatatypeConverter
    .parseHexBinary(keyHex), "AES");
System.out.println(everything);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter
    .parseHexBinary(everything));

System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result));

Cipher cipherd = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
cipherd.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

byte[] result2 = cipherd.doFinal(result);
System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result2));

}}
```

Comment: Where is the error being thrown?

Comment: `byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter
    .parseHexBinary(everything));` Here @jhpratt

Comment: I'm not familiar with the crypto library you're using (or implementing?), but is it possible that you need to prepend `0x` to the string?

Comment: You're passing a string with the entire file content (including newlines) to `DatatypeConverter .parseHexBinary(everything)` - likely that this method doesn't like newlines in the string.

Comment: Can you put some code sample how to stop including new lines? Thanks . @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: **hexBinary needs to be even-length: fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff** f  When i not include new lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
String content = new Scanner(new File("E:\\TESTS\\tests.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    System.out.println(content);
```

This did the magic, removed the spaces.